# React.js key generation

Tags: hashmap, key, reactjs

I've a problem with the Reconciliation algorithm using a set of key (without duplicates). The snippet of code is similar to the examples:
`

```
var ResourceTable = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: [{"rid": "Ciao ", "id": 10}, {"rid": "Mondo!", "id": 2}]};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        self = this;
        self.setState({data: [{"rid":"first", "id": 3},{"rid":"second", "id": 1},{"rid":"third", "id": 2}]});
    },
    render: function() {
        var commentNodes = this.state.data.map(function (resource, index) {
            return (
                <Resource key={resource.id} rid={resource.rid}/>
            );
        });

        return(
            <table>
                {commentNodes}
            </table>
        );
    }
});
```

`
The first time that the object is rendered everything works fine (for every value of the resource.id). The second time I've an unattended behavior: sometimes every element is correctly rendered and sometimes not, I made a lot of attempts, but I cannot find an explanation.
The case that cause the error is:

- First rendering keys: [10,2]
- Second rendering keys: [3,1,2]

The result is that only two element are rendered during the second rendering.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal demo?  I don't think there's enough info here to give an answer.

Comment: Posted the entire component.

Comment: A minimal demo would include the Resource component.  This is likely where the problem is.

Comment: React + <table> = instant failure :D I'm wondering if React team knows how common this error is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React is very sensitive if you are rendering HTML which is mutating in browser. This is the case with `<table>`, which can be created like this:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
</table>
```

But in fact browsers are changing it to:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After this operation DOM and React Virtual DOM differs and triggers errors like yours. To fix it just change:

```
return (
    <table>
        {commentNodes}
    </table>
);
```

into:

```
return (
    <table>
        <tbody>{commentNodes}</tbody>
    </table>
);
```